# Key error while running a Python program with getitem

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, keyerror

The code below creates this error when ran on Amazon Linux 2. The intent is to have the python program respond to user input from a discord server. I know just enough to get me here about python. Any help is appreciated. They server is running an updated version of Amazon Linux 2.

```
File "./bot.py", line 65, in <module>
    client.run(os.environ[config.discord_key])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SuperSecretSquirrelStuff-key'
```

---

````
import discord, asyncio, os, boto3, config

client = discord.Client()

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance_id = config.instance_id
#Temp
instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    memberIDs = (member.id for member in message.mentions)
    if client.user.id in memberIDs:
        if 'stop' in message.content:
            if turnOffInstance():
                await client.send_message(message.channel, 'AWS Instance stopping')
            else:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Error stopping AWS Instance')
        elif 'start' in message.content:
            if turnOnInstance():
                await client.send_message(message.channel, 'AWS Instance starting')
            else:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Error starting AWS Instance')
        elif 'state' in message.content:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, 'AWS Instance state is: ' + getInstanceState())
        elif 'reboot' in message.content:
            if rebootInstance():
                await client.send_message(message.channel, 'AWS Instance rebooting')
            else:
                await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Error rebooting AWS Instance')

def turnOffInstance():
    try:
        instance.stop(False, False)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def turnOnInstance():
    try:
        instance.start()
        return True
    except:
        return False

def getInstanceState():
    return instance.state['Name']

def rebootInstance():
    try:
        instance.reboot()
        return True
    except:
        return False


client.run(os.environ[config.discord_key])```
````

Comment: Is there an environment variable `SuperSecretSquirrelStuff-key` set?

Comment: I have a second file called config.py that contains a variable set to instance_id and discord_key. The SSSS-key here is a place holder for my actual token that is stored in config.py and is returned with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read from a system environment variable, which clearly hasn't been set hence the `KeyError` (as `SuperSecretSquirrelStuff-key` doesn't exist as a key in [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ)).

I can see that you've used the `config` object before to read, for example, `instance_id`.

In that case, read directly from your configuration instead of doing `os.environ` if you want the value of `discord_key`:

`client.run(config.discord_key)`

---

Or alternatively (not sure why you would like to do this) set the environment variable before reading it:

```
os.environ[config.discord_key] = "VALUE";
client.run(os.environ[config.discord_key])
```

Comment: OMG! You are a beautiful human being! Thank you. I feel silly now but I spent way too much time on staring at this thinking.... it's passing the variable but not working. This makes sense and thank you for expanding on your process.

Comment: Haha, thank you :) Enjoy the weekend & have fun with AWS!

Answer (score 0):

According your error message, there is no environment variable "SuperSecretSquirrelStuff-key" in your system.

Here is the code can recurrent your problem:

```
import os
print(os.environ["ANY_KEY_NOT_EXIST"])
```

To resolve this problem, you should add the environment variable "SuperSecretSquirrelStuff-key"  into your system.

For example, execute this code line in your terminal shell:

`export SuperSecretSquirrelStuff-key=xxx`

By the way, the environment key "SuperSecretSquirrelStuff-key" might be invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have this variable declared in a dependency called config which is imported. The variable is named discord_key and contains a string that is my discord bot’s token. When this error is returned on my end, displayed is my token as a string.

Comment: Where would I need to place this export?

Comment: This solution would also work! I am choosing to go a different route in order to keep things more organized for my brain but, thank you for your time and input! Much appreciated!