# How can I fix a KeyError when connecting to cloudsql?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to a cloudsql server using `google.cloud.sql.connector`, with this code taken from the docs:

```py
def connect_with_connector(self) -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
        """
        Initializes a connection pool for a Cloud SQL instance of Postgres.

        Uses the Cloud SQL Python Connector package.
        """
        # Note: Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not
        # secure - consider a more secure solution such as
        # Cloud Secret Manager (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to help
        # keep secrets safe.

        instance_connection_name = os.environ[self.keys["gProj"]]
          # e.g. 'project:region:instance'
        db_user = os.environ[self.keys["gUser"]]  # e.g. 'my-db-user'
        db_pass = os.environ[self.keys["gPass"]]  # e.g. 'my-db-password'
        db_name = os.environ[self.keys["gDB"]]  # e.g. 'my-database'

        ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if os.environ.get(self.keys["gPrivIP"]) else IPTypes.PUBLIC

        # initialize Cloud SQL Python Connector object
        connector = Connector()

        def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
            conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
                instance_connection_name,
                "pg8000",
                user=db_user,
                password=db_pass,
                db=db_name,
                ip_type=ip_type,
            )
            return conn

        # The Cloud SQL Python Connector can be used with SQLAlchemy
        # using the 'creator' argument to 'create_engine'
        pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            "postgresql+pg8000://",
            creator=getconn,
            # ...
        )
        return pool
```

I give it the connection name with `instance_connection_name`, but it then gives me this error:

```
instance_connection_name = os.environ[self.keys["gProj"]]
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: '--connection_name_here--'
```

I've double checked that the connection name is correct and I've messed around with the IPs, does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: `self.keys["gProj"]` is None (empty). It should contain a string value.

Comment: Can you have a look at this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69768691/18265570)?

Comment: @JohnHanley, `self.keys["gProj"]` points to the project name string in the format `"project:region:instance"`, it isn't empty.

Answer (score 1):

I realised it was an issue with `os.environ`, I don't know why the example uses it but I just passed the arguments straight to the connector instead and it worked fine.

```py
def connect_with_connector(self) -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
        """
        Initializes a connection pool for a Cloud SQL instance of Postgres.

        Uses the Cloud SQL Python Connector package.
        """
        # Note: Saving credentials in environment variables is convenient, but not
        # secure - consider a more secure solution such as
        # Cloud Secret Manager (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to help
        # keep secrets safe.

        ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if os.environ.get(self.keys["gPrivIP"]) else IPTypes.PUBLIC

        # initialize Cloud SQL Python Connector object
        connector = Connector()

        def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
            conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
                self.keys["gProj"],
                "pg8000",
                user=self.keys["gUser"],
                password=self.keys["gPass"],
                db=self.keys["gDB"],
                ip_type=ip_type,
            )
            return conn

        # The Cloud SQL Python Connector can be used with SQLAlchemy
        # using the 'creator' argument to 'create_engine'
        pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            "postgresql+pg8000://",
            creator=getconn,
            # ...
        )
        return pool
```